Raccourcir le néopronom « iel » à l'oral
Dans mon français oral, j'ai l'habitude de raccourcir les pronoms il et elle de plusieurs façons:

Quand le prochain mot commence par une consonne, je dis souvent i (comme dans hiver) et a (comme dans attend). Par exemple, i peut pas venir, ou a va venir un peu plus tard.
Quand le prochain mot commence par une voyelle, je dis toujours i, mais je prononce comme si on avait ajouté un y au début du mot. Par exemple, i'avait (yavait) d'autres choses à faire ce soir.
Par contre, si le prochain mot commence par une voyelle, je dis elle. Par exemple, elle a dû rester au travail un peu tard.
Cas particulier: je dis un espèce de èè un peu rallongé au lieu de elle est. Par exemple, e'est pognée dans le traffic.

Tout ça c'est bien mais là je me demande s'il existe quelque chose de semblable pour le néopronom iel. À mon avis, une des raisons pourquoi qu'on a de la misère à s'en habituer c'est parce que c'est encore un peu formel et maladroit, et à chaque fois que je m'en sers à l'oral j'ai le goût de raccourcir un peu de la même façon.
Donc, voilà ma question: est-ce que vous avez entendu des formes raccourcies du néopronom, ou peut-être auriez-vous le goût d'en proposer? Merci!

En effet. Je n'ai jamais vécu au Québec mais ma famille vient de là, donc oui je parle un peu comme eux

@françois-jurain [...] ce qui est une des raisons pourquoi l’on voit des hommes, indifférents aux femmes les plus belles, en aimer passionnément certaines qui nous semblent laides. Marcel Proust, La Prisonnière.

Je pense surtout qu'on ne s'habitue pas à "iel" parce que ça ne fonctionne pas dans une langue romane (et plein d'autres) où l'on doit accorder l'adjectif. On dit iel est beau ou iel est belle ?

Je me posais la même question, je dis aussi beaucoup "y peut" et "è peut" à l'oral et le l disparaît souvent, avec "iel" on a moins cette facilité.
Je pense que ça émergera naturellement avec l'usage courant, dans les cercles qui l'utilisent régulièrement en premier. J'imagine quelque chose comme "yè", à voir comment ça se décante avec le temps.
On peut noter aussi le pronom ael qui a émergé plus récemment. Il a l'avantage de ne pas juste être une fusion de "il" est "elle", en plus du fait de commencer par une voyelle distincte qui permet l'apocope de la dernière syllabe comme pour les deux autres pronoms. Selon moi ça lui permettrait de mieux s'adapter au langage courant, en particulier dans le cas décrit dans la question.
